# Outlook not allowing Office attachments to be opened

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

In Outlook, you can open attachments by double-clicking the attachment. When I try to do this for Office attachments (.docx, .pptx, etc.) I get an error message saying that the respective program failed to open the file. All other attachment types work correctly. The only way around this is to save the document somewhere, right-click, go to Properties, and click Unblock. The document then opens normally.

How can I bypass this step and allow Office attachments to be opened directly from Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your Office program (Word, Excel, you should do this for all of them separately)
2. Click `File` tab and select `Options`.
3. Click `Trust Center` and click on `Trust Center Settings…` button.
4. Click to select `Protected View`.
5. Uncheck `Enable Protected View for Outlook attachments`.

Now try to open the attachment in Outlook please.